# PyGTK how to detect UpClick on a button

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I would like to know how can I detect an "Up-Click" (When i release the click of my mouse) from a simple button ?

Here for a simple press :

```
eventbox.connect('button-press-event', callback)
```

And for a Un-Press ? :

```
eventbox.connect('button-unPress-event', callback)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual term is "release", so:

```
eventbox.connect('button-release-event', callback)
```

Comment: Ahah, now it seems to me so obvious... Thank you!